# Source map error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL: http://{mywebsite}/js/app.js Source Map URL: bootstrap.js.map-laravel-Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

While posting the posts I am getting the above error on the web console.

Source map error: request failed with status 404 Resource
Resource URL: http://{mywebsite}/js/app.js
Source Map URL: bootstrap.js.map

My resourcses/js/app.js looks like this

```
    [const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    msg: 'Update new Post:',
    content:'', 
    },
    methods:{
        addPost(){
            
            axios.post('myid.web/home/addPost', {
                content:this.content
            })
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
});][1]
```

And the webpack.js looks like this

```
 let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

[My partially working output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RMsl.png)

[And my error looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwviq.png)

Comment: can you  show me your  routes file?

Comment: Is it needed ? Because it think it's an error in mapping the source file. And i am unable figure out how to do it.

Comment: run `npm run dev`, it's not being compiled or something

Comment: also see the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend#writing-javascript

Comment: Sir i HV done that at the first place.

Comment: i have resolved the issue . if any one interested you can comment below

Comment: I'm interested ! could you please show us the solution @BiswasSampad

Comment: I ll show tmrw. I am outside

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Please post the answer if you have it.

Comment: Laravel version ?

Comment: Add .sourceMaps() between mix.js line and .sass line than run npm run production

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue and followed Biswas comment. Go to your webpack.mix.js and change

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

to

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```